# How to check in javascript the checkout form Woocommerce before validation?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-form-validator

I would like to test if my form is valid or not (in Javascript). I can not find a way to do it in Javascript. I tried this :

```
if(checkoutForm.checkValidity()){
   console.log("Form is valid!");
}else{
   console.log("Form is invalid!");
}
```

But the problem with this is that it doesnt tell you if the ZIP code is good or not. I would like to use the same check form than Woocommerce.

Comment: here is list of js events - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already tried this. The problem is, i think, the ZIP code. So if i have a wrong ZIP code for a country, I can just trigger the error when I submit the Checkout form. I can not find a way to check this ZIP code in JS (with a Woocommerce).

Comment: Since its ajax you can trigger notices and pass type of notice too - https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_print_notices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the ZIP code. In JS, woocommerce doesn't verify if the ZIP match with the country. Woocommerce use the WC_validation to verify the ZIP code when you click "place older". Unfortunately I had to use PHP (call AJAX) with this [WC_validation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Validation.html#method_is_postcode) :

```
if (WC_Validation::is_postcode( $postcode, $country ) ) {
      echo "ZIP Code OK";
}else{
      echo "ZIP Code NOK";
}
```